# Save a sparse array in csv

Tags: matlab

I have a huge sparse matrix `a` and I want to save it in a `.csv`. I can not call `full(a)` because I do not have enough ram memory. So, calling `dlmwrite` with `full(a)` argument is not possible. We must note that `dlmwrite` is not working with sparse formatted matrices.

The `.csv` format is depicted below. Note that the first row and column with the characters should be included in the `.csv` file. The semicolon in the `(0,0)` position of the `.csv` file is necessary too.

```
;A;B;C;D;E
A;0;1.5;0;1;0
B;2;0;0;0;0
C;0;0;1;0;0
D;0;2.1;0;1;0
E;0;0;0;0;0
```

Could you please help me to tackle this problem and finally save the sparse matrix in the desired form?

Comment: I have done some changes on my post. I hope this will remove the down votes and attract interest:)

Comment: You could use iteration. However, if the matrix is really huge and very sparse, you can also consider only saving the non-zero values and their indexes. Is that an option?

Comment: Question: how large is the original matrix? Larger than 26 x 26? If so, where do you go after Z? (AA?)

Comment: @jan de Gier I have to load the csv in a program that demands this format. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @jan deGier my first thought was to do it iteratively but I didn't found a way yet.

Comment: @njkt The size of the matrix is for example: `20x30000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this iteratively, as follows:

```
A = sprand(20,30000,.1);

delimiter = ';';
filename = 'filecontaininghugematrix.csv';

dims = size(A);
N = max(dims);

% create names first
idx = 1:26;
alphabet = dec2base(9+idx,36);
n = ceil(log(N)/log(26));
q = 26.^(1:n);
names = cell(sum(q),1);
p = 0;
for ii = 1:n
    temp = repmat({idx},ii,1);
    names(p+(1:q(ii))) = num2cell(alphabet(fliplr(combvec(temp{:})')),2);
    p = p + q(ii);
end
names(N+1:end) = [];

% formats for writing
headStr = repmat(['%s' delimiter],1,dims(2));
headStr = [delimiter headStr(1:end-1) '\n'];
lineStr = repmat(['%f' delimiter],1,dims(2));
lineStr = ['%s' delimiter lineStr(1:end-1) '\n'];

fid = fopen(filename,'w');

% write header
header = names(1:dims(2));
fprintf(fid,headStr,header{:});
% write matrix rows
for ii = 1:dims(1)
    row = full(A(ii,:));
    fprintf(fid, lineStr, names{ii}, row);
end

fclose(fid);
```

The `names` cell array is quite memory demanding for this example. I have no time to fix that now, so think about this part yourself if it is really a problem ;) Hint: just write the header element wise, first `A;`, then `B;` and so on. For the rows, you can create a function that maps the index `ii` to the desired character, in which case the complete first part is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csvwrite` function:

```
csvwrite('matrix.csv',a)
```

Comment: I want to save the A, B, C symbols as well. Moreover, csvwrite is not defined for sparse matrices. I have tried `dlmwrite('my_data.csv',full(a), ';')` but I have memory problems because the matrix a is very big. I think the solution is to do this iteratively.